# Definition of 'Record'

Tags: data-structures

Given the definition of 'record': *"a collection of field values for a given entity"*, is this a set of field values for ALL the fields of the entity, or only one particular field [so that you get a different set for each field]?
Also, is the relationship b/w a field & field value essentially equivalent to a function?

**NOTE: Total beginner learning data struc. & algos.**

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER**SCIENCE** @SE. There is a third possibility: it is *literally* what the definition says - a *set* of values (most useful when it allows identifying the entity characterised - and gives additional information). Have a look at the [tags](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags): there is one *about how specific notions have to be understood*: [tag:terminology]. (I remember the terms used from "(entity" relational databases" rather than from *data-structures*.)

Answer (score 1):

All of the fields.  For instance, here is an example of a record:

```
{name: D.W., favoritecolor: blue}
```

You can think of a record as a function from field (key) to value.  For instance, the above would correspond to a function $f$ defined by $f(\text{name})=\text{D.W.}$, $f(\text{favoritecolor})=\text{blue}$.

Comment: Even if a field is blank its contents to to making the up the record. Though you can describe unique records while leaving out common or empty fields they are still part of its definition.

Comment: @Elliot, sorry, I don't understand you.  Perhaps you would like to write your own answer?